# Xib launch screens don't show up on iPhones

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode6, xib

I have designed a launch screen using the interface builder in a xib file. In the general project setting, the Launch Screen xib is selected to be the launch screen. The screen works well on an iPad but just shows a black screen (which is what is supposed to be shown IF no launch screen is designated) on simulator iPhones.

Did anyone else encounter this problem? And how do you fix it.

Comment: Is "Use as Launch Screen" enabled in File Inspector related to the Xib?

Comment: @GonjiDev yes, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this a random problem with the simulator as, after running the project a few more times, it sometimes shows the launch screen and sometimes not.